# VB.NET mysqldatareader miss the first line

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using a stored procedure to get multiresults from a database. If I test the stored procedure in workbench it works perfectly. When I use it in VB.net the datareader miss the first line of each result. Here it is the code:

```
    Dim RData As DataTable = New DataTable

    comando.CommandText = String.Format("call EmailPagoCliente({0},{1},{2},{3})", numCliente, IDPR, IDRes, IDCC)
    conex.Open()
    result = comando.ExecuteReader
    While result.HasRows
        result.Read()
        RData.Clear()
        RData.Load(result)
        correo.Data = RData.Copy
    End While
    conex.Close()
```

The most interesting part of this issue is the the stored procedure has one result that I copied of another stored procedure that works good. Why "result" miss first line?
I used the VB.NET debug and this doesn't happens when the result is loaded in the datatble, it hapens before, when result.read is executed result comes without first line.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the line `result.Read()`?

Comment: understood what is the problem, has to eliminate result.read

Comment: `result.Read` reads the first record but you don't do anything with it. A DataReader is forward only. When your code gets to `Load` the DataTable it is on the second record.